# Let $a,b \in A^+_{\leq 1}$ then $\|a-b\|\leq 1$

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $a,b \in A^+$ such that $\|a\| \leq 1$ and $\|b\| \leq 1$. Then $\|a-b\| \leq 1$.

I have to prove the above, **without** assuming that $ab=ba$.

I don't know how to start with the proof. Any hints are welcome

Thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1822620/

Answer (score 7):

The element $a-b\in A$ is selfadjoint, and it satisfies 
$$
-b\leq a-b\leq a.
$$
So 
$$
-1\leq-\|b\|\leq-b\leq a-b\leq a\leq\|a\|\leq 1.
$$
This shows that $\sigma(a-b)\subset[-1,1]$ and so $\|a-b\|\leq1$.

Note that the inequalities above also prove the slightly sharper inequality 
$$
\|a-b\|\leq\max\{\|a\|,\|b\|\}.
$$