# A question about projections in a C* algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

I have been struggling to prove the following result from a long time. The result is that for any two projections $p,q$ in a C* algebra $A$, we must have $||p-q||\leq 1$. This seems to me an astonishing result because if the strict inequality holds then there will alway exist a continuous path $\varphi:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A)$ with the end points bein $p$ and $q$, which alone gives rise to many other interesting consequences.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result actually holds for $p,q$ positive, they don't have to be projections. This was answered [two days ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208573/let-a-b-in-a-leq-1-then-a-b-leq-1/2209660#2209660).