# About extreme point in C*-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let A be a C*-Algebra.

Prove the extreme points of $(A_{s.a.})_{1}$ are the self-adjoint unitaries in A.

I am reading the proof from notes on Von Neumann algebras by Peterson in page (14,15), but I have some problems in understanding details.

> **APPLICATIONS OF FUNCTIONAL CALCULUS**
> $\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(a-x_{-}\right)+\left(b-x_{-}\right)\right) .$ Since $x$ is an extreme point we conclude that $x=$ $a-x_{-}=b-x_{-}$ and hence $a=b=x_{+}$
> We have shown now that $x_{+}$ is an extreme point in $\left(A_{+}\right)_{1}$ and thus by part
> (i) we conclude that $x_{+}$ is a projection. The same argument shows that $x_{-}$ is also a projection, and thus $x$ is a self-adjoint unitary.
> (iii) If $x \in(A)_{1}$ such that $x^{*} x$ is not a projection then by applying functional calculus to $x^{*} x$ we can find an element $y \in A_{+}$ such that $x^{*} x y=y x^{*} x \neq 0$ and $\|x(1 \pm y)\|^{2}=\left\|x^{*} x(1 \pm y)^{2}\right\| \leq 1 .$ Since $x y \neq 0$ we conclude that $x=$ $\frac{1}{2}((x+x y)+(x-x y))$ is not an extreme point of $(A)_{1}$

1- why if $x_+$ and $x_-$ are projection, then we can conclude that x is unitary?( x is a self-adjoint element with norm one)

2- If $1= \frac{a+b}{2}$ where a and b are self adjoint element and $||a||=||b||=1$ , how by using functional calculus we can prove that $a=b=1$.

Comment: Thank you, every x can be written x=(x+x)\2 , if x is extreme point then x=x\2 then x=0 and it is clear 0 is an extreme point because summation of two positive which are not zero can not be zero.

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your comment, but I'm deleting my comment because it is all in reference to things that are gone from your question.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have, since $x_+x_-=0$, that  $$ x^*x=x^2=(x_+-x_-)^2=x_++x_-=|x|.$$ The assumption is that $|x|$ is a projection; let $q=I-|x|$. Then  $$x=\frac12\,(x+q)+\frac12\,(x-q),$$ so by $x$ being an extreme point we get that $x=x+q$, so $q=0$. That is $|x|=I$.
2. I cannot image what functional calculus has to do with this. You have, for any state $f$, 
   $$
   1=f(I)=\frac12\,(f(a)+f(b))\leq\frac12\,(|f(a)|+|f(b)|)\leq\frac12\,(\|a\|+\|b\|)=1.
   $$
   It follows that $f(a)=f(b)=1$. As we can do this for any state $f$, we have that $f(I-a)=f(I-b)=0$ for all states. As states separate points, $I-a=I-b=0$.

Comment: Thank you for help. Why It follows that f(a)=f(b)

Comment: As for your first question, if you have two numbers in $[0,1]$ and their sum is $2$, then both numbers are $1$.

Comment: In the same note, if $x \in (A_s.a.)_1$ and $x_+ = \frac{a+b}{2}$ for 
$ a,b \in{(A_+)_1}$, then from the fact that $ax_{-}=x_{-}a=0$ and $bx_{-}=x_{-}b=0$. it concludes that $a-x_{-}$ and $ b-x_{-}$ must be in $ (A_s.a.)_1$ I cannot see why $||a-x_{-}|| \leq 1 $?

and also in the same theorem in this note it is proven that every extreme point of unit ball must be is partial isometry.
I cannot see why
 
$||x(1+ y)||^2=||x^* x(1+ y)^2|| \leq 1$ 
what about the converse? Is every partial isometry an extreme point of unit ball? I had some mistake in question, just corrected.

Comment: About  $\|a-x_-\|$, that [was asked here a month ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208573/let-a-b-in-a-leq-1-then-a-b-leq-1). For the inequality, you choose a function with $0\leq t(1\pm f(t))\leq1$, which is nonzero on some part of $\sigma(x^*x)$ far from $0$ and $1$, and let $y=f(x^*x)$.

Comment: Should not it be $0 \leq t(1\pm f(t))^2 \leq1$?
I tried but could not produce a continuous function that $f(t)\subset [0,1]$, because $ y \in (A_1)+$, and fits the inequality. Could you please give me a hint?
In C*-Alebra by Pedersen in page 4, there is a proposition which proves every unitary is an extreme point of unit ball.

Comment: If $ 1=\frac {x+x^*}{2}$ where $x \in (A)_{1}$, I see x is normal but how from functional calculus we can conculude that $x=1$.

Comment: I answered that, it was your point 2. As I said, I cannot imagine what it has to do with functional calculus.

Comment: Yes, the discussion above works for this case too, in most theorem they just conclude everything with functional calculus, and sometimes I really cannot find relation. Thank you very much

Comment: As for the $f$, I'll let you think of the details. What you need is an $f$ that consists of a little "bump" over a small interval $[a,b]$, with $0<a<b<1$, such that $\sigma(x^*x)\cap[a,b]\neq\emptyset$.